# How to hijack Firefox API in addon?

Tags: firefox-addon

I want to hijack the `SetPosition` API of a `nsIBaseWindow` object, is there any way to do it in an addon?

Answer (score 0):

No, unfortunately.  The addon API lets you extend firefox through certain hook positions, and it's not really possible to replace existing internal API calls.  You need to modify the base source code itself for things like that.

Sometimes, you can achieve the effect you want by finding the object you want to change a property of *after* the information has been set by the base code and altering or changing it later.